# String matching of variables with white spaces using stringdist package

Tags: r, string-matching, stringi, stringdist

I am trying to match the strings in a dataset with jaro distance. The problem is I am getting strings with white spaces as matches. Here is the data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID1=c("london.inc","USA","UK","ball"," "),ID2=c("london.in","US","UKS","bull"," "), x=c(1:5))
library(stringdist)
df1$jwdist<-stringdist(df1$ID1,df1$ID2,method='jw',useBytes=TRUE,p=0)
y <- subset(df1,df1$jwdist<.2)

     ID1       ID2 x     jwdist
1 london.inc london.in 1 0.03333333
2        USA        US 2 0.11111111
3         UK       UKS 3 0.11111111
4       ball      bull 4 0.16666667
5                      5 0.00000000
```

Is there a way I can handle the matches which are of white spaces? I am expecting output like this.

```
  ID1       ID2 x     jwdist
1 london.inc london.in 1 0.03333333
2        USA        US 2 0.11111111
3         UK       UKS 3 0.11111111
4       ball      bull 4 0.16666667
```

Comment: Can't you just remove these rows before running `stringdist`? For example, `df1 <- subset(df1, rowSums(df1 == " ") < (ncol(df1) - 1L))`

Comment: I am merging two different  data sets. Both of which have a lot of variables >10 of strings and numbers. I tried issuing the command and it is taking all the white spaces in the data frame. I just want to strip white space from one column.

Comment: So strip the white spaces from that column?

Comment: If i strip of the white space still the jw distance will be 0. I need to match the columns for cross checking the data inconsistencies. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand you. Your desired output strpis the rows with both white spaces completely. Can you provide an example where my suggestion doesn't work? BTW, you can modify my code to just `df1 <- subset(df1, rowSums(df1[1:2] == " ") < 2) ` for example.